# Double integral notation for bounds.

Tags: calculus, notation

> Calculate the double integral $$\int\int_R x\sin(x+y)dA$$
>
> where $R=[0,\frac{\pi}{6}] \times [0,\frac{\pi}{3}]$

I don't need the solution I would just like to know if this means

$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{6}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{3}x\sin(x+y)d
ydx$$

or

$$\int_0^0\int_\frac{\pi}{6}^\frac{\pi}{3}x\sin(x+y)d
ydx$$

I'm used to the notation $R = \{\begin{bmatrix}x \\y\end{bmatrix}\in \mathbb R^2:a \le x\le b \, \, , c\le y \le d\,  \}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing $[a,b] \times [c,d]$ is a shorthand for 
$$
R = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: a \leq x \leq b, c \leq y \leq d\}.
$$

Comment: It is also literal:  if $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is understood as the first copy is the $x$-axis and the second copy the $y$-axis, then that rectangle is the literal Cartesian product $[a,b] \times [c,d]$.